# Get all nested arrays from ElasticSearch document and sort it

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping similar to this: [JsonExample](http://pastebin.com/P8Mv5mgC)

This represents a changelog structure. So each document represents an object with certain properties. These properties can be changed at certain dates. To limit the space, it keeps track of the changes instead of updating the whole object with only one updated field for example.

The goal is to query a certain object based on a given date. The result should be the object with the properties on that given date. So later changes should be discarded and only the changes matching or most recent to  the given date should be returned.

So with a nested query I can retrieve the whole object. Now I only want those nested properties to be returned and also sorted closest to the given date so I can easily find the properties at that given date.

Is there any way to do this with only ElasticSearch queries/filters and without parsing the returned json and sort afterwards with for example Java.

Comment: This questions inst very clear to me. Could you clarify with a lot more detail as to specifically what you are looking for?

Comment: I rewrote the question and hope it is more clearly now.